# How to update meta value to exactly what it appears at frontend?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, frontend, metadata

I tried updating a meta value from wordpress frontend using the following code:

```
function code_form()
{
$content = '';
$content .= '<h2> code </h2>';
$content .='<form method="post">';
$content .='<input type = "text" name="code"/>';
$content .= '<br /><input type="submit" name="Activate" value="continue">';
$content .= '</form>';
return $content;
}
add_shortcode('form1','code_form');

function a()
{
if(isset($_POST['Activate']))
{
    $input = sanitize_text_field($_POST['code']);
    $current_user_id = get_current_user_id();
    update_user_meta($current_user_id, 'metakey_' ,$input);
    echo "<script>alert('success')</script>";
}
}
add_action('wp_head','a');
```

And the input value should be something like:

a:1:{i:0;s:1:"1";}

However, when I check phpmyadmin for the updated result, something different is stored, such as

s:1"a:1:{i:0;s:1:"8";}" 
How should I change my code to make the stored value exactly same as my input?

I tried deleting the metakey and update the value, but still doesn't work.

Comment: Looks like this field stores a serialized value, but by already passing a value in that format from the frontend, you end up with a double serialized value. Can you explain _why_ you want to input it in this format in the first place? That is probably not a good idea anyway, because it is easy to make mistakes if one tried to create/manipulate that format "manually".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input data is serialized twice that's why it happens, try to pass an array

```
$input = explode(',' , $input);
```

[Here is the same question asked](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/68075/serialized-data)